# How to make one main.CSS instead of HTML subpages

Tags: html, css, web, program-entry-point

I would like to have one main.CSS for my portfolio website (Where I can put different images and texts on each subpage) but I don't know how this works. So I have now 10 different HTML files for every subpage, which is very stupid of me. I would really appreciate it, if you could help me (I'm sorry but I'm just a beginner in HTML and CSS) Thanks in advance!

```css
.dash_horizontal{
      border: 0 none;
      border-top: 1px dashed #322f32;
      background: none;
      height:0;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 40px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    } 
    
    h1 { 
      font-family: helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: -10px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: -10px;
    }
    
    p { 
      font-family: helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: 11px;
    }    
    #column-left {
      float: left;
      width: 14%;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #column-right {
      float: left;
      width: 10%;
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    
    }    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px dashed #000000;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-right: 1px;
      border-left: 1px;
      border-top: 1px;
      font-family: helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 21px;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      padding: 14px;
      border: 1px, dashed #000000;
      border-style: none none dashed;
      color: #000000;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
    <img src="images/logo_3.jpg" title="logo" alt="image1">
 
    <div class="dash_horizontal"> </div>
    
    <div id="column-left">
    
    <h1> hello world </h1>
    
    <div id="column-right">
      
    <div class="table">
    
    <table width="50%" border="0" align="center"> 
        <tr>
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_1.html"> <img src="images/frame_1.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image1" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td> 
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_2.html"> <img src="images/frame_2.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image2" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td> 
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_3.html"> <img src="images/frame_3.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image3" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td>
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_4.html"> <img src="images/frame_4.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image3" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td> 
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_5.html"> <img src="images/frame_5.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image5" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td>   
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_6.html"> <img src="images/frame_1.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image6" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td> 
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_7.html"> <img src="images/frame_2.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image7" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td> 
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_8.html"> <img src="images/frame_3.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image8" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td>
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_9.html"> <img src="images/frame_4.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image9" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td> 
        <td>text<br /><a href="Page_10.html"> <img src="images/frame_5.jpg" 
        style="border:0px solid black;" alt="image10" width="190" height="140"/></a>
        <br />info</td>   
        </tr>  
    
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Move the CSS code to a separate file "main.css"; the in your html pages you'll add: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />` preferably between your <head></head> tags.

Answer (score 2):

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) has a great tutorial for beginners. Simply create your external CSS page and then reference it in each of your HTML pages.

Something like:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Then pull your code out of the HTML pages and drop it into the "mystyle.css" external CSS page.

Answer (score 1):

Save your css in a seperate file (you can name it something like style.css).
Then include this tag inside your *head* tags in your .html files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

For every .html file that includes this tag inside it will apply the linked .css file.

Answer (score 0):

In css file you can only place :

```
.dash_horizontal{
  border: 0 none;
  border-top: 1px dashed #322f32;
  background: none;
  height:0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
} 

h1 { 
  font-family: helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: -10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

p { 
  font-family: helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: 11px;
}    
#column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 14%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#column-right {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 20px;

}    
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px dashed #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-right: 1px;
  border-left: 1px;
  border-top: 1px;
  font-family: helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 21px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 14px;
  border: 1px, dashed #000000;
  border-style: none none dashed;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

I think you think about templates for each page. You need to use for example PHP. But this is different story. You need to check, if your server support php, then you need to use simple php [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to solve this problem. Of course, you can use the database but it's more complicated.